# What exact happen between beforeunload and unload event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, timing

I refreshed the same page using Chrome browser (macbook) several times, and found that there is a big duration between `beforeunload` and `unload` events, randomly from 10ms to 5000ms. This confused me, and I tried to find out why but got no answer. So what exactly happen in the `unloading` process? Why does this happen?

Here are my measuring codes (with the preserve log option checked, or the log will be cleared when refreshing the page):

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    console.time('unload duration')
})
window.addEventListener('unload', () => {
    console.timeEnd('unload duration')
})
```

Comment: What was the page? Or at least what kind? Running this on `about:blank` takes me 3-4 ms. Did it have a lot of content/scripts running?

Comment: I got these data from Chrome Network Tool (transferred size/resources size): page(1.1MB/3.1MB) js(973KB/2.7MB) css(39.8KB/184KB)

Comment: Hmm... my best guess is that it has to make sure everything on the page unloads/closes properly without leaking memory. Browsers are very complex programs. If you want, you can take a look at the Chromium [source code](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/55f44515cd0b9e7739b434d1c62f4b7e321cd530/chrome/browser/ui/unload_controller.cc) for the Unload Controller.